# Angularjs2 the same service doesn't share data?

Tags: angular

I have the following service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TopplayersService {
  private topPlayers: TopPlayers[];

  constructor() {}

  private getTopFromServer() {

    if (!this.topPlayers) {
      console.log(this.topPlayers);
      // get from server
      this.topPlayers = TOPPLAYERS;
    }
    // return the cached version
    return this.topPlayers;
  }
```

Now when I have a component that uses this service and I create this component twice (in the html there are 2 tags for it)

I have noticed that **getTopFromServer** will always log **this.topPlayers** as undefined and thus will always query the server

Why is that? I'm pretty sure that a service is shard among all the components who uses it

EDIT: this is how I inject the service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'top-players',
  template: require('./top-players.html'),
  styles: [require('./top-players.scss')],
  providers: [TopplayersService],
  directives: [],
  pipes: []
})
export class TopPlayersComponent {
  @Input()
  // from where to start to take the top players (1 for example)
  start: number;
  @Input()
  // where to end the top players (5 for example)
  end: number;

  topPlayers: TopPlayers[];

  constructor(public topplayersService: TopplayersService) {}
  onSummonerClick(player) {
      alert('clicked on: ' + player.name);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.topplayersService.getTop(this.start,this.end).then(topplayers => this.topPlayers = topplayers);
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you inject the `TopplayersService` in the component?

Comment: @PierreDuc  constructor(public topplayersService: TopplayersService) {}

Comment: Where are you providing this TopplayersService? If it is on your component level, each component will have its own instance. You should provide it on a higher level if you want to share the service between components.
<edit> Ah, you are indeed provided it at the component itself. Try to move it to a higher level (e.g. application). For more information about this hierarchical dependency injection, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: What @Sjoerd says.. that's the solution :)

Comment: @Sjoerd Oh I see thanks, probably missed this part in the tut :)

Comment: @Sjoerd if you add it as an answer kfir124 can accept it and the question is shown as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share a service over multiple components, you need to provide the service at (shared) parent. In your example the service is injected for each component, meaning that each component has its own instance of the service.

For more information about the hierarchical dependency injector please check the documentation on the Angular2 website: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html